# Evaluating backup services, preferably compatible with rsync?

Tags: backup, rsync, online-backup

I'm looking for a backup service and the cost is the most important factor.

In order to properly evaluate the **cost per year** I will use the following data: **50 GB** space usage and the transfer is not bigger than 100 GB.

Also it is important to be able to do the backup/restore using a multiplatform sync tool, preferably **rsync**.

Please do not a suggest self hosted solution and please provide the estimated yearly cost.

Comment: Consumer questions and web services are considered out of scope on Superuser. Voting to close.

Comment: Off-topic on the grounds that this is a shopping question.

Answer (score 0):

[Dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/plans) handles accounts in that range and they definitely have the multi-platform aspect done right

Disclosure: no connection except as a satisfied customer, I've not looked much at alternatives because it worked out of the box.